# A little vb.net interface explaination

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, interface

Can anyone explain the (of Out T) component to this interface? I'm familar enough with how interfaces work. I also understand that T refers to a type... Whats going on with the Out portion.

```
Public Interface IPageOfItems(Of  Out T)
Inherits IEnumerable(Of T)
        Property PageNumber() As Integer
        Property PageSize() As Integer
        Property TotalItemCount() As Integer
        ReadOnly Property TotalPageCount() As Integer
        ReadOnly Property StartPosition() As Integer
        ReadOnly Property EndPosition() As Integer
    End Interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.0 introduced [covariance and contravariance of generic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). Here's what this means.

### Covariance

The `Out` keyword here indicates that the type is **covariant**. A covariant type `T(Of D)` can be cast to a type `T(Of B)` where D derives from B. This is possible when the type `T(Of D)` only ever uses D values as *output* (hence the word **Out**).

For example, the `IEnumerable(Of Out T)` interface is covariant because none of its methods accepts any parameters of type `T`. Therefore, an `IEnumerable(Of String)` can be cast as an `IEnumerable(Of Object)` -- if it provides enumerable access to strings, then it provides enumerable access to objects (since strings *are* objects).

### Contravariance

Conversely, the `In` keyword may be applied to a type that is eligible for **contravariance**. A contravariant type `T(Of B)` can be cast to a type `T(Of D)` where D derives from B. This is possible when the type `T(Of B)` only uses B values as *input* (hence the word **In**). In other words, contravariance is the exact opposite of covariance.

A good example of a contravariant type would be the `IComparer(Of In T)` interface. This interface provides no methods that return `T` values; therefore an `IComparer(Of Object)` could be cast as an `IComparer(Of String)` -- after all, if it can compare objects, it can compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is to indicate the interface is covariant in generic parameter T. Check Generic Variance heading in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336123.aspx) that explains new features in VB.NET 2010 (.NET Fx 4.0).

In short covariance will allow to substitute smaller type (such as subclass) instead of larger type. For example, if Tiger is inherited from Animal then we can use IEnumerable(Of Tiger) in place of IEnumerable (Of Animal). Eric Lippert has explained variance (in context C#) very well in series of [blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).

Answer (score 0):

This is new .NET 4 feature that allows you to specify variance with generic arguments. Pretty much everything you need to know:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx